# How to get a WPF TextBlock to scroll where the Text property is set asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, textblock

I have a `TextBlock`, wrapped in a `ScrollViewer`, and the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` is set with the result of a Task. The scrollbars of the `TextBlock` do not adjust to the size of the text returned by the task.

Any ideas?

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 Height="177" 
                 Width="500" 
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
      <TextBlock Height="177" 
                Text="Extracted Xml" 
                Width="504" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ScrollViewer` calculates it's scrollbars based on dimensions of child controls.

Thus, remove `Height` property from your `TextBlock` and ScrollBars should work as expected

Comment: `MaxHeight` also should be removed if present.